# WordPress & BuddyPress Outputting PHP to page

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have a section of code inside a cusomtised BuddyPress widget (latest-articles.php) which is falling over on the => part and outputting everything after that to the screen. Here is the code section:

```
    $infohub_args = array(
    'post_type' => array('article','post'),
    'posts_per_page' => 8, 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$infohub_loop = new WP_Query($infohub_args);
```

This is what outputs to the screen instead of the widget contents:

> array('article','post'), 'posts_per_page' => 8, 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_status' => 'publish' ); $infohub_loop = new WP_Query($infohub_args); */ $post_max = 8; $all_post = array(); $article_cat = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'articles', 'hide_empty' => true ) );

Basically everything after the ' => ' part is displayed on the screen.

Is this a PHP configuration or version issue?

This is on a Windows 10 / IIS 10 machine.

Comment: Í dont think it is issue of php configuration or short tag(doc http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) because php closing tag must be '?>' to check where there any space between '=>'

Comment: short_open_tag was off, updated it in php.ini and it now works:

Comment: short_open_tag = On

Comment: Many thanks - post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There you wont allows for short open tag `<?` (which is discouraged
>   since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini
>   configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the
>   --enable-short-tags option).

refer doc http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php